# SharePoint c# caml query two joined lists

Tags: c#, join, sharepoint

Hi I have two lists in sharepoint:
1,Page- Id, title
2,Fragment- TableAId, article

One page can have more fragments.

Is it possible to join these two lists and get in C# one object with nested list of articles?

I saw its possible by caml query but I am not successful so far.
I tried code as its in the picture

I tried this caml query in the picture. And googled in stack overflow. It should be possible but I don't know how...

Comment: Please don't post images of code. They don't allow people to copy/paste for testing and are not recognizable by screen readers (for visually impaired people).

Comment: Here is a document about CAML Query List Join Operation With SharePoint App Model, please refer to it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/caml-query-list-join-operation-with-sharepoint-app-model/